# Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'split')

Tags: javascript, split, undefined

I am trying to use 'split' in nodejs and I am getting can not read property of undefined (reading 'split') error. Does anybody have a clue how I can solve this?
Here is a snippet of my code. I am using node version 16.13.1.

```
***var config = require('./decrypt.js');
var temp = config.replace('{','');
temp = temp.replace('}','');
temp = temp.split(',');
var userArr=temp[0];
var passArr=temp[1];
var serverArr=temp[2];
var dbArr=temp[3];
var usertemp = userArr.split(':');
var passtemp = passArr.split(':');
var servertemp = serverArr.split(':');
var dbtemp = dbArr.split(':');***
```

Comment: What is the value of `config`?

Comment: `Split` is a method of String.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. If you get stuck, post a minimal reproducible example of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the `[<>]` snippet editor.

Comment: Based on the magics with `{`, `}`, `,`, and `:`, you are probably looking for something like `var temp=JSON.parse(config);`. That strange file is probably a JSON, see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Objects/JSON or http://www.json.org/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can debug your code or log it to the browser's, e.g. Chrome, dev console to determine which variable is undefined.

```
var config = require('./decrypt.js');
var temp = config.replace('{','');
temp = temp.replace('}','');
console.log({ config : config, temp: temp });
temp = temp.split(',');
console.log(temp);
```

[image: Chrome dev]

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use split on array, its for String.

You can only use it on a String